# UnicodeDecodeError on fetching an Url

Tags: python-2.7, urllib2

I'm very new to python 2.7 and reading data from a URL using urilib2 and writing to a normal txt file,

```
webPage = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.somewebsite.com').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(webPage)
urlData= open("urlData.txt","a+")
div  = soup.find("div",{"class":"imgMrgnTopLG imgMrgnBtmLG listBullet"})

for row in div.findAll('ul'): 
        for li in row.findAll('li'):
             if any( ext in li.text.encode('utf-8') for ext in keys):
                    urlData.write(li.text.encode('utf-8')+"\n")
```

Upon executing the above code, I'm facing this error, I have tried the previous solutions, but unable to fix. please help me, thank you in advance.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```